# Opencv3: Error when import cv2 in python OSX el capitan

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.1

I was installed OpenCV 3.1 on mac OSX, I also create a symlink in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages: 
cv2.so -> /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

But when I import cv2 in terminal i got this error:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/webp/lib/libwebp.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Then I tried to install webp using mac port:

```
sudo port install webp
```

But after that i still got the error above when import cv2 in python:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/webp/lib/libwebp.6.dylib
```

Comment: I tried to reinstall opencv3 with option --with-webp but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and after run `brew install webp` it simply fixed the import issue on python.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/compiling#building). Installed webp using macports not solve the problem, I have to install webp follow this step:

- Download libwebp-0.5.1.tar.gz (not libwebp-0.5.1-mac-10.9.tar.gz) from [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html)
- Untar the package:

`tar xvzf libwebp-0.5.1.tar.gz`

- Go to the directory where libwebp-0.5.1/ was extracted to and run the following commands:

  cd libwebp-0.5.1

  ./configure

  make

  sudo make install

That's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install `brew install webp` but for this lib you need to install libpng first with `brew install libpng`

if you are using [this](http://www.mobileway.net/2015/02/14/install-opencv-for-python-on-mac-os-x/) to install opencv you need to link! because you are tap in brew with `brew tap homebrew/science` for this use this:

```
brew link --overwrite libpng
brew link --overwrite webp
```

but first of all test without linking it should be enough (: